# Concatenating two really large dask dataframes

Tags: python, concatenation, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I have many large datasets (large as in larger than the RAM) on which I want to perform Filters, Joins and Concats. Pandas failed since each dataset size (around 25GB) is larger than my RAM (16GB).
I am now trying to use Pandas instead of Dask. Each large dataset is now stored in chunks as a series of parquet files.

There are three scenarios

1. Perform operations such as filter and join on the large dataset and store the result to disk.
2. Concatenate two or more large dask dataframes and store the result back to disk
3. Perform 1 and 2 together.

It is important to note that, in most cases the result from any of the above 3 scenarios is still larger than the RAM, hence .compute() is not desirable.

**What I've tried:**

Lazily perform all calculations, perform "dask.dataframe.to_parquet()" and write the results to disk, instead of using .compute(). This works for a few cases such as filtering, but fails for operations such as sort, union, drop_duplicates.

**What I am trying to solve:**

A failproof way to obtain the result and store it to disk without causing memory errors.

**Example**

```
dask_df1 = dd.read_parquet('path_to_data1/data1.*.parquet')
dask_df2 = dd.read_parquet('path_to_data2/data2.*.parquet')
union_df = dd.concat([dask_df1,dask_df2])
filtered = union_df[ *some filtering condition* ]
result = filtered.merge( *with some other large dask dataframe* )
```

It is trivial that `result` too shall be larger-than-memory. Using `result.compute()` would raise `memory_error`.

Comment: What's your end goal? After you've concatenated the data frames, what comes next?

Comment: Perform filters/merges/group-by aggs or save it in disk before.

Comment: I recommending not calling `.compute()` until after you've declared all of those operations

Comment: What do you suggest to do when the result after all these operations might still be larger than available memory? (Say, the result is 25GB and RAM is 8GB)

Comment: I really need more context as to what you're actually trying to achieve. Without that, the best I can say is, "it depends".